# Conflict Google Plugins FCM Plugin and Google Geolocation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have ionic 3 application and I have used FCM Plugin and GeoLocation Plugin but when I trying to use the app and make a build it is showing a warning message (developer warning for package XXXXXXX failed to post a notification on channel "null" see log for more details)

so please if anyone can help

on ios, it is working well

waiting for your help

thanks